# Set up Phemex API trading

Tags: python, api, jupyter-notebook, bots

I try to set up a crypto-trading-bot, which can go short- and long-positions. So I created a phemex account and tried to implement a bot in jupyter notebook using python.
I created API key and secret on phemex.
I wrote the following code:

```
from phemex.client import Client
from phemex.exceptions import PhemexAPIException
import websocket, json, pprint, talib, numpy, requests

API_ID = "..."
API_SECRET = "..."
SOCKET = "wss://testnet.phemex.com/ws"

client = Client("API_ID", "API_SECRET", True)

def on_open(ws):
    print("opened connection")

def on_close(ws):
    print("closed connection")

def on_message(ws, message):
    print("received message")
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    pprint.pprint(json_message)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open =on_open, on_close =on_close, on_message = on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

With this code, I want to get the actual data for Bitcoin from phemex. If I do it for Binance it works just fine. Can some help me with this issue?

Thank you

Best regards
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You can get data from Phemex like this.

```
from phemex_python_api.phemex.client import Client
client.query_24h_ticker("BTCUSD")
```

To place an order:

```
client.place_order({"symbol":"DOGEUSD","clOrdID":"cryptomarauder1","side":Client.SIDE_BUY,"orderQty":1000,"ordType":Client.ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,"priceEp":0.2250,"takeProfitEp":0.25,"stopLossEp":0.20})
```

There is an issue with the API because setting the stop loss and take profit does not work for me. I already opened an issue [here](https://github.com/phemex/phemex-python-api/issues/1).

Feel free to use the [documentation](https://github.com/phemex/phemex-api-docs/blob/master/Public-Contract-API-en.md#placeorder) as a guide.

You can set Leverage like this:

```
# Set leverage
try:
    # Set 0 to change back to cross margin
    # Set to 10x 
    r = client.change_leverage(Client.SYMBOL_BTCUSD, 10)
    print("response:" + str(r))
except PhemexAPIException as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Hello Karl, thank you for answering this. Is there a possibility to place a order with for example leverage of 5?

Comment: Hi, I'll add a leverage example to my answer

Comment: Hi, if i try to install phemex using 'pip install phemex' there is an error 'ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement phemex (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for phemex' What can I do here?

Comment: Do you have a solution for this?